# Acquisition of data from non automated old machinery in IIOT

Tags: sensors, industry-4.0

Could you tell me how to get the data from the non automated old machinery using Industrial Internet of Things?

Comment: Provide more information about the machinery and the environment, if you want a proper answer

Comment: This sort of "IoT retrofit/update" could potentially be a very interesting and on-topic line of questioning.  It does need more specifics, though a lot of the challenge is not with the machine-specific data acquisition *sensors* but with the hardware/operating system/application software *infrastructure* which facilitates the collection.  To fit on the site, starting with a representative goal ("detect/report bearing failure by vibration") might be best, even if that is only the pathfinder through the architectural needs for something which then becomes generic.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way is to attach external module with MCU or even single board computer , running network stack and proper application to sensors, which are already integrated into your machinery. In this case you should only care about proper interfacing (digital and/or analog) and writing relevant application. In case, if your machinery have no built-in sensors you should integrate them, which is not so easy - this task requires some skills in field of mechanical engineering as well.